# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 50176 into shape (224,224,3)

Tags: keras, web-deployment

I have the error "cannot reshape array of size 50176 into shape (224,224,3) I can't see why this happens maybe somebody had the same problem,

```
def model_predict(img_path,model):
    size=224
    img = cv2.imread(img_path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    img = cv2.resize(img,(size,size))

    img=np.array(img).reshape(-1,size,size,3)
    img_class = model.predict_classes(img)
    return img_class
```

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: File "C:\Users\bibisha\Desktop\New folder\app.py", line 112, in upload
    preds = model_predict(file_path,model)   
  File "C:\Users\bibisha\Desktop\New folder\app.py", line 87, in model_predict
    img=np.array(img).reshape(-1,size,size,3)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 50176 into shape (224,224,3)

Comment: Edit your question and add it, don;t post it as comment

Comment: File "C:\Users\bibisha\Desktop\New folder\app.py", line 87, in model_predict
    img=np.array(img).reshape(-1,size,size,3)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 50176 into shape (224,224,3)

Answer (score 0):

Your image is gray scale (single channel), but you try to reshape it into RGB (3 channels) which will not work.

Try to change line 3

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

into

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```